# How to create elements on the page from JSON array in NativeScript?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm trying to find a way to create elements from JSON array in a nativescript page.

to give you an example:

in simple javascript/jquery, you could simply read JSON data and turn the data into HTML elements on your page.

But this is not really as simple in nativescript. in fact, nothing seems to be simple in nativescript as the developers made it sound to be on their official website. `The Doc is so badly written as if they only wrote it for themselves to understand`!

is there any staright forward way of achieving this?

I'm using Javascript and Nativescript sidekick.

**EDIT:**

To avoid confusion, I'm gonna explain a simple scenario:

lets say I have an external PHP file that outputs this JSON:

```
[{
    "ID": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "New York"
}, {
    "ID": "2",
    "name": "Dave",
    "age": 20,
    "city": "London"
}]
```

Now I need to know a way to read this in Nativescript and then create elements inside the app.

by elements I mean the usual stuff that user click/tap on etc.

I hope its clear now.

Comment: Can you attach a [playground](https://play.nativescript.org) that describes what you have tried already?

Comment: @IanMacDonald, only if i could! I don't even know where to start with this platform (NativeScript). so far I found no infromation related to this question on their website or anywhere else & I even found code snipts (not related to this question) on their own offical site that are wrong or outdated! this platform is an absolute mess. I don't really understand all the hype about it!

Comment: It sounds like you're struggling. Try out the playground that I linked to you and see if that helps answer your questions. As it is right now, there simply isn't enough of a question here.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes I am deffo struggling. not because I don't know what the playground is or because I don't know what NativeScript is but because of lack of information about this platform. I know how to use playground. that's where i started using Nativescript. what i don't know is that `'how to read JSON data from a say external PHP file that outputs a JSON data and create elements in nativescript'`.. and that is what this question is for.

Comment: @IanMacDonald to prove my point regarding this platform being a mess, you can try to create a new project using sidekick. the one titled (Master-Detailed with Firebase) and try to run that project/app on your device. you will see even that doesn't work. no data, no nothing...

Comment: [Here is a playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=5g6Sw4) that demonstrates building a UI using an array of JavaScript objects using Vanilla NS and JavaScript. I created this by saying "New > NS + JavaScript" and then dragging a List View from the bottom right palette. Instead of having it hard-coded, you could make a network call to fetch the data from your "external PHP file", then parse the JSON into JavaScript objects that fit into the array. If you need further help, you're going to have to make your question more specific.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, that helps. thanks. there is actually a Template in sidekick that does exactly what you've provided in the playground and i've used that as the base of my app. What I need to find out is how to `fetch the data from the external PHP file`. for example, in jquery, you have `AJAX` call. what is the equivalent of that in Nativescript?

Comment: I also know there is this: https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http

Comment: From the document you _just_ linked, here's an [updated playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=5g6Sw4&v=2) from earlier.